# Export an image as pdf that acts as a link mathematica

Tags: export, web-access

**Anyone knows if it is possible to export an image as a pdf and this image should act as a link to a website when one clicks on it form within a pdf viewer ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried

```
Export["link.pdf", Hyperlink[
    Plot[x, {x, -2, 2}], 
    "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179748/export-an-image-as-pdf-that-acts-as-a-link-mathematica"
    ]]
```

and the resulting `link.pdf` indeed has a plot that is a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :))

Answer (score 2):

```
SetDirectory@$TemporaryDirectory;
Export[
 "Test.pdf",
 Hyperlink[
  RandomImage[1, {100, 100}],
   "http://www.wolfram.com"
  ]
 ];
 SystemOpen@"Test.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)) It works ! Nice